# How do you get more Expedition Ships and what is the total amount in the game?

Tags: disgaea-5

In the Nether Research Squad shop you start with 3 ships and after finishing a few quests you end up with 5. Are there any more ships that you can get and if so, how many more are there and how do you unlock them?

Comment: I will also say After episode 7 i got one more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 10 expedition ships altogether, which are unlocked as you finish the story.  I don't know which part you get the last ship from, but by PostGame you will have all 10.

Note: assuming you haven't already found that out, this is mainly for anyone else who is curious.